# Copy specific columns in all rows from sheet 1 to sheet 2 based on condition

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-statements

I tried using the code below but it display the entire row in the new sheet. Is there a way that i can move only specific columns to the new sheet by modifying the vba macro code below? 
Thanks in advance!

```
Sub CopyExpired()

    Dim bottomB As Integer
    bottomB = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("sheet1").Range("B1:B" & bottomB)
        If c.Value = "expired" Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe if you remove .EntireRow from c.EntireRow.Copy?

Comment: Note: Don't use `Integer` when counting rows, Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Always use `Long` instead of `Integer` there is no benefit in `Integer` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an .AutoFilter.

```
Sub CopyExpired()

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="expired"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                        Destination:=Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                End If
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this vba macro code but it still display the entire row in the new sheet

Comment: I guess you should have provided more detail than *'only specific columns'*.

Comment: The first column comprises of dates and the second column is the status(expired/not expired). I need a vba macro code which move the dates in first column which are expired to sheet 2 instead of moving both columns to the new sheet.

Comment: So when you say *'copy specific columns'* you actually meant *'move one column'*? btw, copy and move are two different things.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to excel, what i meant was copy.

Comment: Btw how to modify the code if i want to copy mulitiple columns to sheet 2? (For example column A, C and E)

Comment: There isn't anywhere to put an answer and that sounds like a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
c.EntireRow.Copy
```

with

```
Range("C" & c.Row & ",E" & c.Row & ",H" & c.Row).Copy
```

and you can select what columns to use

Answer (score 0):

if I didnt do the syntax 100% right then sorry. Dont have excel near me.

1st: please dont use A1 codes in your macros. Rather use the R1C1 method as follows:

```
dim sh as worksheet
set sh =activeworkbook.activesheet
sh.cells(1,2) = "Test worked!!"
```

'this will put the text into row 1 column 2 of your sheet.

2nd: you could copy each cell via a subroutine.

for example:

```
dim rw1 as integer, lastRw as integer, cellsToRight as integer
lastRw = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
for rw1 = 1 to lrw
 for col=1 to 10
  sh.cells(rw1,col + cellstoright)=sh.cells(rw1,col)
 next col 
next rw1
```

or you could just do the colums yourself manualls, eg... array of integer with the values 1,3,4,6,7,8 ... and then loop over the array with your integers as columns, same thing as the above loops.